# Nested requests with Scala and play Framework

Tags: asynchronous, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

I'm working with Play Framework (2.0.4) and Scala, and I have a problem.

I call my backend to get a list of users (in json), and for each user, I have to get extra info from the backend (one request per user).

So in my services, I have :

```
def getUsers(/*different uninteresting parameters*/ ): Promise[List[Option[User]]]
```

and

```
def getExtraUserInfo(user:User):Promise[Option[Double]]
```

So for each User which is returned by getUsers, I want to call getExtraUserInfo, and return the user plus the extra info about each user.

So in my controller, i've tried to do something like that :

```
def getUsers(/*parameters*/) = AuthenticatedAsync{ request =>
val users = UserService.getUsers(/*parameters*/)

  users.flatMap {
  case Some(userList) => 
    Ok(Success("users" -> Json.toJson(userList.flatMap{
      user => UserService.getExtraUserInfo(user).map {
        case Some(price) => user.price = price
          user
        case _ => user
      }
    }.map(_.json))))
  case _ => InternalServerError(Error("error while getting users", Errors.TECHNICAL))
}
}
```

Do you guys have any idea how to do it ? (this code doesn't work, but that's all I managed to do...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Promise.sequence` to sequence a list of promise.
Promise.sequence transforms a `List[Promise[T]]` to a `Promise[List[T]]`...

see [the Play! Scala API here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise%24)